# TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to save adresses Details - prestashop new

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I have a big problem (I found out that a lot of prestashop users had/have this problem and there are a lot of suggestions, I have tried everything without success) when you complete the address form and click save, I'm getting a message box with:

> "TECHNICAL ERROR: unable to save addresses Details: Error thrown:
>   [object Object] Text status: parsererror" and X (close).

If I click close, I can complete the order, but it's not very nice for visitors and clients to receive this error.

I found something with disable canonical url, something with the below line in `frontcontroller.php`:

```
$match_url = rawurldecode(Tools::getCurrentUrlProtocolPrefix() . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (!preg_match('/^' . Tools::pRegexp(rawurldecode($canonical_url), '/') . '([&?].*)?$/', $match_url))
```

I don't know how to change this or if this is the problem.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you enabled the dev mode? In `defines.inc.php` set to true `_PS_MODE_DEV_`

Comment: If you active development console in your browser you could see ajax requests. Check the ajax related with this error and in request response you will probably find what is going wrong. Good luck.

Comment: Please try repeating the step after enabling error debugging and post the issues shown here so that we can help you accordingly.

FYI, to enable error debugging you can follow the steps below.

- open file: config/defines.inc.php (using FTP or hosting control panel)

- change false-->true:

    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
    
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);